# Bootstrap navbar on smallscreen no dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

On smaller devices on clicking the burger icon, a drop down menu of the navbar should be shown.

In my original file I downloaded the bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css and linked them. I also linked the jquery library file before the bootstrap.min.js. I have also tried using the CDN link. But still no good result. Of course on resizing the browser size the navbar becomes responsive and turns into the burger icon. But on clicking the icon nothing actually happens.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700');
body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.section {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: #373737;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: normal;
}

h2 {
  color: #454545;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 52px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h3 {
  color: #585858;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h4 {
  color: #656565;
  font-size: 20px;
}

p {
  color: #878787;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
}


/*-------- Navigation section--------*/

.navbar-default {
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 12px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #444;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #858585;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
  padding: 0 12px;
  margin: 15px 8px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li a:hover {
  color: #000 !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background: #000000;
  border-color: transparent;
}


/*=============Home section ===============*/

.home {
  background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

#home {
  background-size: cover;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.home .home-content p {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.home .home-content .site-name {
  border: 4px solid #1a1a1a;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  width: 240px;
  padding: 12px;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.home .home-content h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.home .home-content h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.home .home-content {
  text-align: center;
}

.home .home-content .border {
  border: 4px solid #1a1a1a;
  width: 230px;
  padding: 28px 0px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border-top: 0;
}

.section-btn {
  background: #454545;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1.6px;
  padding: 12px 32px 16px 32px;
  margin-top: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

.section-btn:focus,
.section-btn:hover {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}


/*=============About section ===============*/

.about-social li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.about-social li a {
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 42px;
  width: 42px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 2%;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-social li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #000;
  background: #2d2d2d;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Navigation area -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-main">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
      <!-- Logo text -->
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Maureen.</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-main">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Home section start -->
<section class="home" id="home">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m12 l6 center-align">
        <div class="home-content">
          <h1>HELLO THERE!</h1><br/>
          <p>My name is Maureen</p>
          <h3>I AM A UI/UX DEVELOPER</h3>
          <div class="border"></div>
          <a href="#" class="">Download Resume PDF</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- About section -->
<section class="section" id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="mt-3">
          <img src="images/profile-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block img-thumbnail">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="mt-3">
          <h2>ABOUT ME</h2>
          <h3 class="mt-4">HELLO! <span class="text-custom">I'M MAUREEN DOE.</span></h3>
          <p class="text-muted mt-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tempor sem et nisi efficitur tempor.Phasellus pharetra dolor in enim pellentesque tincidunt vel non nisi. </p>
          <p class="text-muted mt-2">Nullam posuere eu ante ut pharetra. Donec laoreet volutpat viverra. Vivamus ultrices, nibh eu porttitor luctus, odio lacus semper dolor, non scelerisque tellus augue a risus.</p>
          <p class="text-muted mt-2">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec quis ullamcorper tortor. Nulla quis bibendum ex. Etiam eget ullamcorper turpis, eu luctus nibh. </p><br/>
          <div>
            <ul class="about-social list-inline">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-behance"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- End of about section -->


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: there is an error in your snippet

Answer (score 1):

When doing things like this it's important to ensure you're using the library/framework as recommended by the creators.

You should try to keep all your CDN's versioning somewhat similar as best as you can, when it comes to bootstrap. Here are the CDN's listed for [3.3.4](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2015/03/16/bootstrap-3-3-4-released/)

You had 3.3.4 css and 3.3.6 js

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700');
body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.section {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
}

h1 {
  color: #373737;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: normal;
}

h2 {
  color: #454545;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 52px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

h3 {
  color: #585858;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h4 {
  color: #656565;
  font-size: 20px;
}

p {
  color: #878787;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 25px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2px;
}


/*-------- Navigation section--------*/

.navbar-default {
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 12px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #444;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #858585;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
  padding: 0 12px;
  margin: 15px 8px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li a:hover {
  color: #000 !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background: #000000;
  border-color: transparent;
}


/*=============Home section ===============*/

.home {
  background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

#home {
  background-size: cover;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

.home .home-content p {
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.home .home-content .site-name {
  border: 4px solid #1a1a1a;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  width: 240px;
  padding: 12px;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.home .home-content h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.home .home-content h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.home .home-content {
  text-align: center;
}

.home .home-content .border {
  border: 4px solid #1a1a1a;
  width: 230px;
  padding: 28px 0px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  border-top: 0;
}

.section-btn {
  background: #454545;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1.6px;
  padding: 12px 32px 16px 32px;
  margin-top: 42px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;
}

.section-btn:focus,
.section-btn:hover {
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}


/*=============About section ===============*/

.about-social li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.about-social li a {
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 42px;
  width: 42px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 2%;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
}

.about-social li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #000;
  background: #2d2d2d;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Navigation area -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-main" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
      <!-- Logo text -->
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">Maureen.</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-main">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#service">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#resume">Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Home section start -->
<section class="home" id="home">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m12 l6 center-align">
        <div class="home-content">
          <h1>HELLO THERE!</h1><br/>
          <p>My name is Maureen</p>
          <h3>I AM A UI/UX DEVELOPER</h3>
          <div class="border"></div>
          <a href="#" class="">Download Resume PDF</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- About section -->
<section class="section" id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="mt-3">
          <img src="images/profile-image.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block img-thumbnail">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="mt-3">
          <h2>ABOUT ME</h2>
          <h3 class="mt-4">HELLO! <span class="text-custom">I'M MAUREEN DOE.</span></h3>
          <p class="text-muted mt-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tempor sem et nisi efficitur tempor.Phasellus pharetra dolor in enim pellentesque tincidunt vel non nisi. </p>
          <p class="text-muted mt-2">Nullam posuere eu ante ut pharetra. Donec laoreet volutpat viverra. Vivamus ultrices, nibh eu porttitor luctus, odio lacus semper dolor, non scelerisque tellus augue a risus.</p>
          <p class="text-muted mt-2">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec quis ullamcorper tortor. Nulla quis bibendum ex. Etiam eget ullamcorper turpis, eu luctus nibh. </p><br/>
          <div>
            <ul class="about-social list-inline">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-behance"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- End of about section -->


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. That was really helpful. It solved the entire issue. I should keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jQuery and Bootstrap JS to your header.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This fixes the issue. You need these as the navbar on mobile relies on both on jQuery and on Bootstrap JS.

[image: Error fixed]

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue with jQuery 3.x conflicting with Bootstrap 3.x. If you use jQuery lower than version 3, it may work.

Check this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tb5cdLx7/) where I have used jquery-1.12.4.min.js.

> **Note:** this issue has been fixed from Bootstrap version 3.3.7 onwards.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```